# Find pattern with regex in Sublime text 2.02

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I would like to create a new Syntax Rule in Sublime in order to search a string pattern so that that pattern is highlighted. The parttern I am looking for is IPC or TST, therefore I was making use of the following Sublime Syntax rule

```
{ "name": "a3",
  "scopeName": "source.a3",
  "fileTypes": ["a3"],
  "patterns": [

    {  "name": "IPC",
       "match": "\\b\\w(IPC|TST)\\w\\b "
    }
  ],
  "uuid": "c76f733d-879c-4c1d-a1a2-101dfaa11ed8"
}
```

But for some reason or another, it doesn't work at all.

Could someone point me out in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give yaml a try btw, it's a lot easier. You won't need the double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

After looking around and testing a lot, I have found the issue, apparently apart from identifying the patter, I should invoke the colour, for doing it I have to make use of "capture", being the command as follows:

```
  { "name": "IPC colour",
    "match": "\\b(IPC|TST)\\b",
    "captures": {
        "1": { "name": "meta.preprocessor.diagnostic" }
        }
  },
```

Where *"name": "meta.preprocessor.diagnostic"* will indicate the sort of colour assign to the found pattern.

regards!